# TypoScript: Include Right Content Column into Template Typo3 [7.6.10]

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

I want to use the "Right Content" Column in my Template. So i created in the backend some example content like this:
[image: Backend Content]

I wrote the source code of my template on my own. It looks like this:

```
page = PAGE
page.stylesheet = fileadmin/template_ffw/style/style.css
page.typeNum = 0

page.10 = TEMPLATE
page.10.template = FILE
page.10.template.file = fileadmin/template_ffw/index.html
page.10.workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT_BODY

page.10.subparts {
    CONTENT < styles.content.get
    ASSIDE < styles.content.getRight

    MENU = HMENU
    MENU.1 = TMENU
    MENU.1 {
        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap = <div class="level1"> | </div>
    }

}

page.10.marks{
    LOGO = IMAGE

    LOGO.altText = Logo
    LOGO.file = fileadmin/template_ffw/style/ffw_logo.png

    ROOTLINE = HMENU
    ROOTLINE.special=rootline
    ROOTLINE.special.range= 0 | -1
    ROOTLINE.1=TMENU

    ROOTLINE.1.NO.allWrap= |   /   |*| |   /   |*| |        
}
```

At the index.html file i have this source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- ###DOCUMENT_BODY### START-->
  <div id="kopfzeile">
    <div id="logo"><a href="index.php" style="font-weight: inherit; font-size: inherit; font-family: inherit;">###LOGO###</a></div>
    <nav>
        <!-- ###MENU### START-->  
          <a href="einfuehrung.htm">Navigationslink</a>
        <!-- ###MENU### END-->
    </nav>
  </div>
   ###SLIDER###
  <div id="breadcrumb">###ROOTLINE###</div>
  <div id="main">
         <!-- ###CONTENT### START-->
            <h1>Willkommen</h1>
            <h2>Hier soll der Inhalt später stehen.</h2>
            <p>An dieser Stelle soll später der Inhalt von TYPO3 eingefügt werden.</p>
         <!-- ###CONTENT### END-->

   <div id="asside">
         <!-- ###ASSIDE### START-->
              <h1>Example Heading</h1>
         <!-- ###ASSIDE### END-->
   </div>        

  </div>

  <!-- ###DOCUMENT_BODY### END-->
</body>
</html>
```

But on the frontend the content of the Right Column is not displayed. So i have probably a bug in my typoscript. The Frontend Page looks like this:
[image: Page at the Frontend]

I know this is very much source code for a question, but i searched for my Mistake this long, that i'm not shure where it is. And better to much than to less informations. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that. This kind of templating is too long ago for me. I would suggest using the FLUIDTEMPLATE templating possibility. See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in `www/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt` the file `StylesContent.txt` from folder "Helper" is not included automatically anymore.
So I guess you must include
`<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:css_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/Helper/StylesContent.txt">` where getLeft, getRight and getBorder is definded.
Alternatively you can just add this one line after

`ASSIDE < styles.content.getRight
ASSIDE.select.where = {#colPos}=2`

or as I know it from that templating time `ASSIDE.select.where = colPos=2`

Well, but as @Thomas already recommended you should anyways switch to `FLUIDTEMPLATE` but getting the column not directly depends on that. I also just want to make you know that FLUID is the right thing.

Comment: you need to start with `ASSIDE < styles.content.get` and modify the where clause afterwards. But I can't edit the answer as it would change less than 6 characters. (silly SO rule)

Comment: Thank you for your fast anwser. I replaced this Line:
`ASSIDE < styles.content.getRight`
with
`ASSIDE < styles.content.get
    ASSIDE.select.where = colPos=2`
and it works now!
Thank you very much.